# ordering of table data for Primary Key

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table that is like this :

```
create table nasd_snapshot
( minute_id         smallint not null
, symbol_id       integer not null 
...
PRIMARY KEY ( symbol_id, minute_id )
```

Does it matter, or would it make it more efficient, to have the columns in the PRIMARY KEY in the same order as the columns in the table?

I guess I don't know enough about how things are stored internally, but have done some research.  Any suggestions or links to some articles on this appreciated.

THX!

DON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an index ALREADY sorts them. The point of adding an index is to have the data sorted so mysql can fetch the data really fast. It already has the index columns sorted so you do not need to worry about that anymore :) However, as you can imagine, storing data + sorted data takes more space in the server. So do not overdo with indexing. One more thing - PRIMARY index is the same as normal index except it also says that the data in that index's columns will be unique for the table. The best example to try it yourself would be: put some data into your database, lets say 10.000 records. Let them be, for example, `(id, name)`. Try the query something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=6451`. Then add the index (or PRIMARY KEY) on id column. Try again. If you are using PhpMyAdmin, it shows how much time the query took to execute. You will see HUGE difference between the indexed and unindexed cases. Also, take a peek at how much space the table takes.

Comment: Thx for answer.  I understand indexes.  But from what I understood, PRIMARY KEY is special in that it clusters data such that table data is stored on disk in the order specified in the PRIMARY KEY.  So if order in PK is same as order in table definition, I thought that might be more efficient somehow..

Comment: No, it as I said, PRIMARY KEY already adds a unique index. When queried, mysql will look at the index and will fetch the data according to it. Even if the column is completely mixed up, the time it takes to retrieve the record will be the same. It just cannot be otherwise, because it would mess up all the indexing theory.

Answer (score 0):

No, but the order of the Primary key is still important.

If you will be running queries with conditions involving `symbol_id` but not `minute_id` as well as queries involving both then you have it the right way.

If you run a lot of queries where the condition involves `minute_id`, but not `symbol_id` then you'd be better off switching them

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way is to test it yourself. There are users who did find out that the order of columns does matter and others do not. I myself usually just go with the column order in the table definition.

http://ralpartha.blogspot.com/2006/12/primary-key-order-does-matter.html

So if it is possible, you should try both and measure the queries that you typically run.